# Is it "which of these is...", or "which of these are..."

Tags: grammatical-number

I came accross a question in my maths homework which was worded as follows (emphasis mine).

> Which of the following claims ***is*** correct?

After which it goes on to list a collection of claims, two of which are true. My question is if it is grammatically correct to say "***is*** correct" in this context, or if the correct wording is "***are*** correct", assuming the question doesn't want to restrict the set of correct answers to just one.

I think "are correct" is acceptable because the first part, "which of the following" is referring to a subset of the answers (of unspecified size), so it should be referred to in plural.

However, it seems to me that "is correct" can also be acceptable because "which of the following" might be referring to each one individually, then asking about each claim if it ***is*** correct.

So does saying "***is*** correct" limit the solution set to a size of one or not?

Edit: I know the lecturer (who wrote the question) meant there to be multiple correct answers, I am interested in the grammatical correctness of the sentence, and its reasoning.

Comment: Here, the speaker is using 'is' (instead of the ugly 'is/are'). Which is inadvisable. I wouldn't go as far as to say totally ungrammatical, but violating the Gricean maxim of manner (not being as clear as is needed). **But** the speaker disambiguated otherwise, which alters the situation.

Comment: Which is inadvisable? What the lecturer did or the ugly 'is/are'? And why?

Comment: We used to have well-defined rubrics such as 'None, one or more of the accompanying statements a, b, c, d and e will be correct in each question. You will receive a mark for each correct identification but lose one for each incorrect identification, except that a negative total will be adjusted to zero for any given question, and a correct zero (no statements in that question correct, and none judged correct) awarded a single mark.' _And worse_.

Answer (score 1):

I would definitely take the use of the word 'is' to mean that they expect you to choose only one. If you believe there are two or more correct answers, then maybe someone is mistaken (you or the textbook author). Sometimes there are errors in textbooks too!

Comment: Maybe I should have clarified, the lecturer (who wrote the question) clarified that there may be more than one answer. I just want to know if they're mistaken, and more importantly, why. The context is just an example, I am asking about the correct grammar to use in this situation.